# Golang. Zero Garbage propagation or efficient use of memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, go, garbage-collection

From time to time I face with the concepts like **zero garbage** or efficient use of memory etc. As an example in the section Features of well-known package [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) you can see the following:

> **Zero Garbage:** The matching and dispatching process generates zero bytes of garbage. In fact, the only heap allocations that are made, is by building the slice of the key-value pairs for path parameters. If the request path contains no parameters, not a single heap allocation is necessary.

Also this package shows very good benchmark results compared to standard library's http.ServeMux:

```
BenchmarkHttpServeMux         5000     706222 ns/op          96 B/op        6 allocs/op
BenchmarkHttpRouter         100000      15010 ns/op           0 B/op        0 allocs/op
```

As far as I understand the second one has (from the table) no heap memory allocation and zero average number of allocations made per repetition.

**The question**: I want to learn a basic understanding of memory management.  When garbage collector <del>allocates</del>/deallocates memory. What does the benchmark numbers means (the last two columns of the table) and how people know when heap is allocating?

I'm absolutely new in memory management, so it's really difficult to understand what's going on "under the hood". The articles I've read:

- https://golang.org/ref/mem
- https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html
- http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The garbage collector doesn't allocate memory :-), it just deallocates. Go's garbage collector is evolving, for the details have a look at the design document https://docs.google.com/document/d/16Y4IsnNRCN43Mx0NZc5YXZLovrHvvLhK_h0KN8woTO4/preview?sle=true and follow the discussion on the golang mailing lists.

The last two columns in the benchmark output are dead simple: How many bytes have been allocated in total and how many allocations have happened during one iteration of the benchmark code.  (This allocation is done by your code, not by the garbage collector). As any allocation is a potential creation of garbage reducing these numbers might be a design goal.

When are things allocated on the heap? Whenever the Go compiler decides to! The compiler tries to allocate on the stack, but sometimes it must use the heap, especially if a value escapes from the local stack-bases scopes. This escape analysis is currently undergoing rework, so it is not easy to tell which value will be heap- or stack-allocated, especially as this is changing from compiler version to version.

I wouldn't be too obsessed with avoiding allocations until your benchmarking show too much GC overhead.

Comment: @OP - "undergoing rework" in this instance means that there are times where variables escape during escape analysis that shouldn't - and the Go team are aware of that. That means you're getting heap allocations when really you should be getting a stack allocation. There's a fascinating document on that somewhere (I can't seem to find it on go-dev at the moment). "Escape analysis" the term will be helpful for your research. Nice answer Volker :)